# How to "glue" two Android applications into one?

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I am currenty working on two applications in Android Studio.

The first one is using a sensor from which reveices data and makes some computations regarding them and the second one is an Augmented Reality application(using Metaio) who detects human body and generates a heart on user's chest.

I have developped them sepparately but I want to be part of the same app. Like when I enter in the application to have the possibility to choose which of them I want to use and have the possibility to get back to that state in order to use the other one.

Is this possible? If it is, how can be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a high level:

- Make a new project with a simple activity used to pick which mode to run in
- Pull both modules into the new project (and any other modules they may depend on)
- Remove the LAUNCHER attribute from both the original launch activities, the new launcher will be the new activity you just made
- Write your new activity, with a branch that either loads an intent for your first apps usual LAUNCHER activity, or your second one

There's not magic process that will do all this for you, but it shouldn't be too hard to do.

Comment: Isn't a way to do the join between the two apps apk files?

Comment: @migea if you don't mind them being separate apps on the phone you could skip right to the last step, all the apps would need to be installed.  However, something that simply takes 2 apks and combines them does not exist AFAIK.